# Renaming with Git: Using git mv vs deleting a file and adding another

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I 'renamed' a file manually by deleting the old one and adding another with the new name. How do I undo this in the commit history and use git mv instead?I need to rebase my feature branch to the updated parent where the old file name is still being used. I don't want to lose the changes from both the old-name file and new-name file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git mv` does the exact same thing as what you did.

When scanning the history, it then tries to spot "renaming" actions by comparing contents, and saying "hmm ... if those two files have 85% content identical, I'll say it's a renaming"

Use `git rebase -m` to tell git to look more carefully for renaming.